# 9 Patch showing Lines - not being recognized

Tags: android, nine-patch

today I started creating and using  9-Pacth images. But my Device does not recognize the 9 Pacth image. I set it as the Background of a Button.
Here you can see:

[image]

Here is my 9 Patch image:

[image]

Can someone say what im doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What's the drawable file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the top and bottom border. The two dots should be on top (stretch marks), the line should be on the bottom (content area).